# i got some errors about a library with .o in the end. i can not figure out what's going on with those options

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

[image: In the image is the whole description of the errors i got]

got errors like:
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/lichallenger/Downloads/Safari_Download/OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide[pdf及源代码]/opengles-book-samples-read-only/iPhone/Chapter_2/Hello_Triangle/../../Common/build/Debug-iphonesimulator'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGImageGetWidth", referenced from:
      _esLoadPNG in ImageUtils.o
  "_CGImageGetHeight", referenced from:
      _esLoadPNG in ImageUtils.o
  "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
      _esLoadPNG in ImageUtils.o
  "_CGBitmapContextCreate", referenced from:
      _esLoadPNG in ImageUtils.o
  "_CGColorSpaceRelease", referenced from:
      _esLoadPNG in ImageUtils.o
  "_CGContextClearRect", referenced from:
      _esLoadPNG in ImageUtils.o
  "_CGContextTranslateCTM", referenced from:
      _esLoadPNG in ImageUtils.o
  "_CGContextDrawImage", referenced from:
      _esLoadPNG in ImageUtils.o
  "_CGContextRelease", referenced from:
      _esLoadPNG in ImageUtils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need to include/add the CoreGraphics library in your frameworks.

Comment: i've already got opgles and quartzcore included, still got this error.is there any way to get rid of the library, cuz i got all source files. i can include these files in my proj.

Comment: Have you added the appropriate #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> statements in classes that need it?  When you added the libraries did you link them in correctly in the build settings for your target?